# m4sugar doesn't seem to work outside of autotools

Tags: bash, macros, autotools, preprocessor, m4

## The Issue

So I've been trying to integrate `m4sugar.m4`, a library of m4 macros defined to make generic programming easier in m4, into a system of macros that I'm building for a bash library of mine to make certain tasks easier and to save on typing, however, whenever I try to use `m4sugar.m4` in m4 I get a humongous list of errors and crap:

### Error Snippet

```m4
# m4_assert(EXPRESSION, [EXIT-STATUS = 1])
# ----------------------------------------
# This macro ensures that EXPRESSION evaluates to true, and exits if
# EXPRESSION evaluates to false.
m4:m4sugar.m4:223: bad expression in eval: [$1]

## ------------------- ##
## 4. File inclusion.  ##
## ------------------- ##


# We also want to neutralize include (and sinclude for symmetry),
# but we want to extend them slightly: warn when a file is included
# several times.  This is, in general, a dangerous operation, because
# too many people forget to quote the first argument of m4_define.
#
# For instance in the following case:
#   m4_define(foo, [bar])
# then a second reading will turn into
#   m4_define(bar, [bar])
# which is certainly not what was meant.

# m4_include_unique(FILE)
# -----------------------
# Declare that the FILE was loading; and warn if it has already
# been included.
m4:m4sugar.m4:275: cannot open `$1': No such file or directory
m4:m4sugar.m4:277: cannot open `$1': No such file or directory



# m4_include(FILE)
# ----------------
# Like the builtin include, but warns against multiple inclusions.
m4:m4sugar.m4:285: undefined builtin `[include]'



# m4_sinclude(FILE)
# -----------------
# Like the builtin sinclude, but warns against multiple inclusions.
m4:m4sugar.m4:293: undefined builtin `[sinclude]'

# m4_argn(N, ARGS...)
# -------------------
# Extract argument N (greater than 0) from ARGS.  Example:
#   m4_define([b], [B])
#   m4_argn([2], [a], [b], [c]) => b
#
# Rather than using m4_car(m4_shiftn([$1], $@)), we exploit the fact that
# GNU m4 can directly reference any argument, through an indirect macro.
m4:m4sugar.m4:444: non-numeric argument to builtin `m4_incr'

# m4_cond(TEST1, VAL1, IF-VAL1, TEST2, VAL2, IF-VAL2, ..., [DEFAULT])
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Similar to m4_if, except that each TEST is expanded when encountered.
# If the expansion of TESTn matches the string VALn, the result is IF-VALn.
# The result is DEFAULT if no tests passed.  This macro allows
# short-circuiting of expensive tests, where it pays to arrange quick
# filter tests to run first.
#
# For an example, consider a previous implementation of _AS_QUOTE_IFELSE:
#
#    m4_if(m4_index([$1], [\]), [-1], [$2],
#          m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\\]) >= 0), [1], [$2],
#          m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\$]) >= 0), [1], [$2],
#          m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\`]) >= 0), [1], [$3],
#          m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\"]) >= 0), [1], [$3],
#          [$2])
#
# Here, m4_index is computed 5 times, and m4_eval 4, even if $1 contains
# no backslash.  It is more efficient to do:
#
#    m4_cond([m4_index([$1], [\])], [-1], [$2],
#            [m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\\]) >= 0)], [1], [$2],
#            [m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\$]) >= 0)], [1], [$2],
#            [m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\`]) >= 0)], [1], [$3],
#            [m4_eval(m4_index([$1], [\"]) >= 0)], [1], [$3],
#            [$2])
#
# In the common case of $1 with no backslash, only one m4_index expansion
# occurs, and m4_eval is avoided altogether.
#
# Please keep foreach.m4 in sync with any adjustments made here.
m4:m4sugar.m4:507: bad expression in eval: [$# % 3]), [2], [m4_fatal([$0: missing an argument])],
       [_$0($@)]
m4:m4sugar.m4:549: undefined builtin `[patsubst]'
m4:m4sugar.m4:566: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_pushdef' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:641: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:546: bad expression in eval: $# & 1), 0, [,]))])])

m4:m4sugar.m4:664: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:673: undefined builtin `[dumpdef]'
sh: []: command not found
m4:m4sugar.m4:706: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:735: non-numeric argument to builtin `m4_decr'
m4:m4sugar.m4:767: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:780: undefined builtin `[m4wrap]'
m4:m4sugar.m4:925: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: m4_default_quoted(,
              1)
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: ((255) - (1)) /  *  + (1)
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: m4_default_quoted(,
              -1)
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: ((1) - (255)) / -() *  + (1)
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `m4_define' ignored
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: _m4_defn() + 0
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: Warning: too few arguments to builtin `m4_translit'
m4:m4sugar.m4:2204: bad expression in eval: _m4_defn() +
m4:m4sugar.m4:2203: ERROR: end of file in argument list
```

## My Question

I'm using the latest version of both `m4` and `m4sugar.m4` and I'm running `m4` using `m4 -P` so that builtins are prefixed with `m4_`; is there something that I'm just missing like does autoconf use a special tool or something to ignore the syntax errors or do I just need to bite the bullet and go through each macro and fix them?

Comment: You're not supposed to use -P with m4sugar.m4. The whole point of m4sugar.m4 (among a few other things) is that it simulates m4_ macro's, while leaving others untouched (like dnl).

Comment: @CarloWood yet, it doesn't seem to work without -P or with -P.

Comment: That is strange. I get no errors when I run `m4 /usr/share/autoconf/m4sugar/m4sugar.m4`